# Deductive closure from Completeness

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

the prompt asks to show that if $\Sigma$ is complete, then it is deductively closed.

I know that deductive closure means $\Delta \vdash \sigma$  implies that $\sigma \in \Delta$.

and that since $\Sigma$ is complete it is closed. but I'm not positive on how to write this into a proof.

Comment: What definition of "complete" are you using? In at least one standard definition, the result stated is false. So the precise definition of each term matters.

Comment: I don't really know... all it says is "complete." My only other context is that it's for a predicate calculus course.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yep. Given the context, "complete" probably means "maximal", or "for every sentence $\sigma$, either $\sigma\in\Delta$ or $\neg\sigma\in\Delta$".

Comment: @BrianO: but a complete-in-that-sense, but inconsistent theory does not need to be deductively closed. If this problem is one of chasing definitions, there's no way to do it without the definitions.

Comment: @CarlMummert Touché. That definition would work for consistent theories, though.

Comment: @J.Marie Does your course have a textbook? If so, surely it defines "complete". If not, then surely the term has been defined already — course notes, etc.

Comment: @BrianO It does but it has multiple definitions and I'm not sure which is pertinent to this question. I'll ask in class tomorrow. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: @J.Marie You're welcome. Asking tomorrow sounds like the best approach.

Comment: The most likely idea is that, assuming $\Delta$ is consistent, if $\Delta \vdash \phi$ then $\Delta$ cannot contain $\lnot \phi$.

Comment: The result holds for any theory $\Delta$ maximal non-trivial with relation to some $\varphi$ (assuming the underlying logic is "classical" enough). Maximal non-trivial wrt $\varphi$ meaning $\Delta \not \vdash \varphi$ and $\Delta, \psi \vdash \varphi$ for any $\psi \not \in \Delta$.